# Adding text on the bottom of slide and changing the color

Tags: beamer

I have a code that gives a beamer presentation. At the BOTTOM Of Every slide , I need something like written in the attached picture and kindly change the color from purple to yellow as in the given figure

I am attaching **LATEX CODE**  &  **DESIRED FIGURE** [image: Desired picture]

```
% Copyright 2004 by Till Tantau <tantau@users.sourceforge.net>.
%
% In principle, this file can be redistributed and/or modified under
% the terms of the GNU Public License, version 2.
%
% However, this file is supposed to be a template to be modified
% for your own needs. For this reason, if you use this file as a
% template and not specifically distribute it as part of a another
% package/program, I grant the extra permission to freely copy and
% modify this file as you see fit and even to delete this copyright
% notice. 

\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}

% There are many different themes available for Beamer. A comprehensive
% list with examples is given here:
% http://deic.uab.es/~iblanes/beamer_gallery/index_by_theme.html
% You can uncomment the themes below if you would like to use a different
% one:
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usecolortheme{crane}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\newcommand{\cvec}[1]{{\mathbf #1}}
\newcommand{\rvec}[1]{\vec{\mathbf #1}}
\newcommand{\minor}{{\rm minor}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\<}{\langle}
\renewcommand{\>}{\rangle}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\rom}[1]{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral #1@}
\makeatother
\usecolortheme{default}
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}

\begin{document}

\title{\LaTeX}

% A subtitle is optional and this may be deleted
\subtitle{Advanced Methodolgy in Mathematics\\
\vspace{5 mm}
Master in Advanced Mathematics}

\author{Amna Alshanbari}
% - Give the names in the same order as the appear in the paper.
% - Use the \inst{?} command only if the authors have different
%   affiliation.
\date{November 25,2014 \\ \includegraphics[width=3cm]{logo}}


%\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{logo}}

%\pgfdeclareimage[height=0.5cm]{university-logo}{university-logo-filename}
 %\logo{\pgfuseimage{university-logo}}

\subject{Theoretical Computer Science}
% This is only inserted into the PDF information catalog. Can be left
% out. 

% If you have a file called "university-logo-filename.xxx", where xxx
% is a graphic format that can be processed by latex or pdflatex,
% resp., then you can add a logo as follows:

% \pgfdeclareimage[height=0.5cm]{university-logo}{university-logo-filename}
% \logo{\pgfuseimage{university-logo}}

% Delete this, if you do not want the table of contents to pop up at
% the beginning of each subsection:

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}{Contents}
\begin{block}{}
  \begin{enumerate}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[circle]
   \item Goals
   \item Columns
\begin{itemize}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[circle]
   \item Text in two columns
   \item Text in three colums
    \end {itemize}
  \item Fundamental Theorem of Calculus
  \item Big Math Expressions \rom{1}
  \item Big Math Expressions \rom{2}
  \item Examples using Ti\textit{k}Z
  \item Examples using  X\textsubscript{Y-pic}
  \item Remarks
  \item Bibliography
\end{enumerate}
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\def\hash{##}

\begin{frame}{Goals}
\begin{block}{}

\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\vbox{%
\everycr{}
\halign{\span\hash\cr
In this assignment you should make an exact copy of this pdf file, chang-\cr
ing your {\color{blue}Name and Surname, today's date} and fixing {\color{blue}several misprints}.\cr
I have introduced in different places (writing the words in {\color{purple}purple}).\cr
\noalign{\smallskip}%
Be aware that you are supposed to mimic not only the text, align-\cr
ments, statements, diagrams and the mathematical
 formulas, but also\cr
the \textit{font} and {\huge size}, highlighted text, the use of $\backslash$\texttt{pause}, $\backslash$\texttt{onslide},\cr
$\backslash$\texttt{only},$\backslash$\texttt{visible}, etc.\hfill\cr}}}
%I have introduced in different places (writing the words in purple 

\end{block}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Second Slide Title}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item {
    First item.
    \pause % The slide will pause after showing the first item
  }
  \item {   
    Second item.
  }
  % You can also specify when the content should appear
  % by using <n->:
  \item<3-> {
    Third item.
  }
  \item<4-> {
    Fourth item.
  }
  % or you can use the \uncover command to reveal general
  % content (not just \items):
  \item<5-> {
    Fifth item. \uncover<6->{Extra text in the fifth item.}
  }
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}{Blocks}
\begin{block}{Block Title}
You can also highlight sections of your presentation in a block, with it's own title
\end{block}
\begin{theorem}
There are separate environments for theorems, examples, definitions and proofs.
\end{theorem}
\begin{block}{}
Here is an example of an example block.
\end{block}
\end{frame}


% Placing a * after \section means it will not show in the
% outline or table of contents.
\section*{Summary}

\begin{frame}{Summary}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item
    The \alert{first main message} of your talk in one or two lines.
  \item
    The \alert{second main message} of your talk in one or two lines.
  \item
    Perhaps a \alert{third message}, but not more than that.
  \end{itemize}

  \begin{itemize}
  \item
    Outlook
    \begin{itemize}
    \item
      Something you haven't solved.
    \item
      Something else you haven't solved.
    \end{itemize}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame with reduced font size}
%\Fontvi
In this assignment you should make an exact copy of this pdf file,chang-\\ing your Name and Surname, today's date and fixing several misprints.\: \\I have introduced in different places writing the words in purple\\
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame with regular font size}
In this assignment you should make an exact copy of this pdf file,changing your Name and Surname, today's date and fixing several misprints.I have introduced in different places (writing\\ the words in purple
%\Fontvi

\end{frame}





% All of the following is optional and typically not needed. 
\appendix
\section<presentation>*{\appendixname}
\subsection<presentation>*{For Further Reading}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
  \frametitle<presentation>{For Further Reading}

  \begin{thebibliography}{10}

  \beamertemplatebookbibitems
  % Start with overview books.

  \bibitem{Author1990}
    A.~Author.
    \newblock {\em Handbook of Everything}.
    \newblock Some Press, 1990.


  \beamertemplatearticlebibitems
  % Followed by interesting articles. Keep the list short. 

  \bibitem{Someone2000}
    S.~Someone.
    \newblock On this and that.
    \newblock {\em Journal of This and That}, 2(1):50--100,
    2000.
  \end{thebibliography}
\end{frame}

    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usecolortheme{crane}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\date{Today's date}
\title{\LaTeX}
\author{N. Surname}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Goals}
  \begin{columns}\column{12.1cm}
    \begin{beamerboxesrounded}[width=12.1cm,shadow=true]{}
      \begin{minipage}{12.05cm}
        In this assignment you should make an exact copy of this pdf
        file, changing your \textcolor{blue}{Name and Surname, today's date}
        and fixing \textcolor{blue}{several misprints} I have introduced in
        diferent places (writing the right words in \textcolor{purple}{purple}).

        \vspace{2mm}

        Be aware that you are supposed to mimic not only the text,
        alignments, statements, diaggrams and the mathematical formulas,
        but also the \textit{font} and {\Huge size}, highlighted text,
        the use of \verb+\pause+, \verb+\onslide+, \verb+\only+,
        \verb+\visible+, etc.
      \end{minipage}
    \end{beamerboxesrounded}

    \vspace{3mm}

    \begin{beamerboxesrounded}[width=12.1cm,shadow=true]{}
      \begin{minipage}{12.05cm}
        \vspace{3cm}
      \end{minipage}
    \end{beamerboxesrounded}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sir, I want this logo on every page. It means on all slides

Comment: @Ahmad I give you an answer (as for your [previous question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/212114)) but this is the last time: this forum is not intended to to make your exercises by others!

Comment: I am very very sorry sir. It will not happen again. Just last time please solve this problem.

Comment: @Ahmad Did you try add my preamble in your complete document?

Comment: I am very sorry sir. It will not happen again. Kindly do this last time.

Comment: trying sir. I will update you

Comment: I am sorry sir. It is not working. It is changing my other things

Comment: @Ahmad What is this "logo" that you mention in your first comment?

Comment: i mean to say that " text in the bottom " . It is not working sir. It is creating other problems. You should take a look at that.

Comment: @Ahmad (Last comment) If I insert my preamble (4 lines) in your document, all is correct...